# Seeking smallest device able to interface with GPS unit?

Tags: gps, hardware-recommendations

For GPS units that talk over USB, what's the smallest device you could plug the GPS in to in the field, in order to upload from the device to the GPS and download from the GPS to the device?  Netbook?  Smartphone?  Ipad? Kindle Fire? other?

I'm looking for more of a turnkey end-user out-of-the-box (insert buzzphrase here) solution that's on the mainstream market.

The application is uploading search segments boundaries and insertion routes for search and rescue teams, before the full IC computer setup arrives.

Comment: What do you want to upload in the field? Waypoints, new maps, target coordinates..?

Comment: Smartphone will be able to do this with Bluetooth or Micro USB

Comment: Micro SD and a Netbook or a smartphone

Comment: My understanding is many/most smartphones will only do USB client mode, not USB server mode, unless you have USB On-The-Go mode available, does that sound right?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a garmin gps you can use an android phone/tablet plus the app [Garmin Exchanger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sibkot.GarminExchanger&hl=en) to put move waypoints and tracks to and from your gps unit. You will also need an android [otg cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005QX7KYU)  and your gps usb cable. It works pretty good. I use a garmin everyday for work and I use that app to email and receive data that I need to use for my gps.

Comment: for the Garmin 62etc models - mass storage based - is it even simpler than that?  Our team still mostly has 60csx (including me) so your solution looks like a good one.  Do you know if there's anything similar for other smartphone platforms, or other non-phone portable devices?

Comment: Just android, iOS is too closed. Although if you had a jailbroken iphone and a camera kit (the sd card reader). You could put data on your microsd card and put it in your gps. That is pretty much as simple as it gets, it does work for the 62csx. Either way (as a mass storage device or not) you need an android phone and a usb otg cable.

Comment: thanks, I'd 'accept' this one though technically I can't prove it out until getting an android.

Comment: I don't speak smartphone (yet) - an 'android phone' includes Samsung Galaxy and the like?  Is it a hardware difference or just an OS difference?

Comment: Pretty much anything that is not an iphone. Samsung, LG, HTC, etc. It is mainly an os difference but an iphone will only run ios and not android. Hope this helps.

Comment: So I have a galaxy tab pro 8.4 with usb otg now - thanks for all the research leads - and garmin exchanger (had to dig to find it, v0.9) isn't recognizing a 62 - in fact, if the 62 is plugged in before you start garmin exchanger, when you start exchanger the samsung notification says 'usb device unexpectedly disconnected' or something like that, then exchanger just says 'please plug in GARMIN'.  Have you seen this behavior?  The garmin exchanger thread is not moving much - probably the developer has bigger fish to fry which is too bad cause it's a very handy app.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry PI is not very big https://virtuabotix-virtuabotixllc.netdna-ssl.com/core/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/IMG_0204-300x254.jpg and RTKLIB runs on PI http://gnss.co/?p=52.

Comment: looks pretty slick though honestly I'm looking for more of a turnkey end-user out-of-the-box (insert buzzphrase here) solution that's on the mainstream market.

Comment: Edit your question and tell it. You can also mention your budget and what you are going to do with your data. Some integrated GPS+handheld units can be acquired together with surveying software.